MAUI Webview for Android is not showing the keyboard when webview's text field is touched
I'm loading android webkit webview in MAUI application. But when I click on an input field in the webview, it's not opening the keyboard. In the application output I get the following messages. This only happened after I updated the project to .NET8. With previous .NET7 version this works.
[InputMethodManager] showSoftInput
[InputMethodManager] The current service view is not the focus view
But I can click other elements like buttons that are in the webview.
I have tried setting webview.focusable = true, webview.focusableInTouchMode = true
Edit:
This is a part of my xaml file where I load the webview as a custom control. This 'myWebView' extends the Android.Webkit.WebView class
<RefreshView x:Name="refreshView"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
             Refreshing="refreshView_Refreshing"
             IsEnabled="false">
    <Grid RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="*">
            <controls:CustomWebView x:Name="myWebView"
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    </Grid>
</RefreshView>

in the custom control
webView.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
 public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
 {
     // Prevent parentes from handling Touch event
     RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
     return base.OnTouchEvent(e);

 }


Is the keyboard covered by the webview or other elements?

No, the keyboard is not getting opened at all

Can you provide some code as a demo? I can test it on my side.

I was able to fix this by removing the isEnabled property in RefreshView.
<RefreshView x:Name="refreshView"
         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
         Refreshing="refreshView_Refreshing">
<Grid RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="*">
        <controls:CustomWebView x:Name="myWebView"
                        HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
</Grid>

